# How do I replace the contents of line 9 after a certain line with a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

The /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml file reads, in part, as follows：

```
    <key name='alternative-port' type='q'>
      <summary>Alternative port number</summary>
      <description>
        The port which the server will listen to if the 'use-alternative-port'
        key is set to true. Valid values are in the range of 5000 to 50000.
      </description>
      <default>5900</default>
    </key>

    <key name='require-encryption' type='b'>
      <summary>Require encryption</summary>
      <description>
        If true, remote users accessing the desktop are required to
        support encryption. It is highly recommended that you use a
        client which supports encryption unless the intervening network
        is trusted.
      </description>
      <default>false</default>
    </key>

    <key name='authentication-methods' type='as'>
      <summary>Allowed authentication methods</summary>
      <description>
        Lists the authentication methods with which remote users may
        access the desktop.

        There are two possible authentication methods; "vnc" causes the
        remote user to be prompted for a password (the password is
        specified by the vnc-password key) before connecting and "none"
        which allows any remote user to connect.
      </description>
      <default>['none']</default>
    </key>
```

Now I want to change the  paragraph of the
false with the string false to true, how should I do this using a shell script?

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you need - are there many other lines in the file with the string False that should not be altered? Do you want to alter some False's but not others - if so what are the criteria for that? For just the sample you provide, a simple `sed 's/False/True/' your_file` would suffice by changing the first instance of 'False' to 'True' on any line where 'False' appears...

Comment: @mattb, There are many more lines in the file with the False string, but I only want to change this one False by setting it to true and leaving the rest of the False unchanged.
How should I do this?

Comment: So is it always the first line after line 9, which has the word 'False' that you want to change to 'True'?

Comment: Actually, you want to change it in the `require.encryption` section? If you don't want to use an xml tool, try something like `sed '/<key name='require-encryption'/,/default/s/<default>false/<default>true/' file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but whatever you actually want, you can call perl from a shell script:

- The following code would only change `true` to `false` on line `5`:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl -pi -e 's/true/false/ if($. == 5)' /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml
```

- Changing `$. == 5` to `$. > 5` would make sure it happens everywhere after line 5

Answer (score 0):

I've understood your question to ask how to change `<default>false</default>` to `<default>true<default>` in the stanza starting `<key name='require-encryption' type='b'>`.

Using an XML parser you can reliably change this based on the structure rather than the physical layout of lines in the file. Here's how you could use `xmlstarlet`.

For the purposes of the example I've converted your snippet into valid XML by wrapping it with `<root>`…`</root>`. Your original will already be valid XML so this edit won't be necessary there, but you may need to be more precise with the XPath match. Use this code to match on an element path of `…/key/default`, where `key` has an attribute `name` having the value `require-encryption`, and change the value for `default` to the literal `true`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//key[@name="require-encryption"]/default' -v true org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml
```

As usual, if you want to do this in-place, use the standard recipe `command > output.tmp && mv -f output.tmp output`. (This is pretty much just what the `-i`/`--in-place` flag in many GNU commands does behind the scenes for you.)

```
xmlstarlet … > org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml.tmp &&
    mv -f org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml.tmp org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml
```